# Having issues breaking out of my If statement

Tags: c#

I have a fairly simple `if` statement that sets a couple of variables each time it goes through the statement. I'm having an issue that when it gets to `AgentsAvailable == 0` or hits the `else` statement it can not revert back to any of the previous statements. Can someone provide some assistance on a way to make it so the statement loops properly each time one of the statements is true and it does not get stuck.

My `if` statement:

```
if (e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable > 0)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => {
        callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();
        callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        callsWaitingText.Text = "Available";
        longestWaitingData.Text = max.ToString();
        longestWaitingText.Text = "Available";
        callimgae.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ScoreBoardClientTest;component/images/circle_green.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    }));
}
else if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > 5)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => {
        callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing.ToString();
        callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        callsWaitingText.Text = "Waiting";
        longestWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.OldestCall.ToString().Substring(3);
        longestWaitingText.Text = "Waiting";
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimerEllapsed, new object(), 0, 2000);
    }));
}
else if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > 0)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => {
        callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing.ToString();
        callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        callsWaitingText.Text = "Waiting";
        longestWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.OldestCall.ToString().Substring(3);
        longestWaitingText.Text = "Waiting";
        callimgae.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ScoreBoardClientTest;component/images/circle_red.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    }));
}
else if (e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable == 0)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action) (() =>
    {
        callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();
        callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        callsWaitingText.Text = "Available";
        longestWaitingData.Text = max.ToString();
        longestWaitingText.Text = "Available";
        callimgae.Source =
            new BitmapImage(
                new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ScoreBoardClientTest;component/images/circle_yellow.png",
                    UriKind.Absolute));
    }));
}
else
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action) (() =>
    {
        callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();
        callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        callsWaitingText.Text = "Available";
        longestWaitingData.Text = max.ToString();
        longestWaitingText.Text = "Available";
        callimgae.Source =
            new BitmapImage(
                new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ScoreBoardClientTest;component/images/circle_yellow.png",
                    UriKind.Absolute));
    }));
}
```

Comment: What does _revert back to any of the previous statements_ mean?

Comment: Is this in a loop? I don't see how it can "loop properly each time one of the statements is true"

Comment: Maybe OP is looking for [`break`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx), but the question is far from being clear...

Comment: You're going to need a loop around this if you want to test, e.g.,  `e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable > 0` again after it was false the first time.

Comment: ok so...new to programming here and my terminology is bad. this I know already.  A break may be what i'm looking for but I've never used a break in an If statement before, just in a case statement. Should I change this over to a Case instead of an If statement?

Comment: Case is also once-through.  If it fails a condition once, it's not going to try again, it'll just go on to the next option.  Then it's done.  If you want it to try again later, you will have to put a loop around it.  And then maybe add code to break out of the loop once you've accomplished what you want to do here.

Comment: so this is the problem. If I loop this then its the only thing that will happen and stuff outside of the loop will never occur. But to make it work the way I want it, it seems I have to loop it. all of theses statements are already inside a if loop and the if statement is a try catch loop. I'm going to update my question to the entire block of code...which is a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a confusion with what `if-else` statements are intended to do.
They are not loops. Their purpose is to supply conditions to the execution of specific code. The first case in which the conditions are met (return `true`) will be executed, while all others won't be. If you define an `else` case, it will be executed when all above cases fail.
The official documentation on this can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5011f09h.aspx).

To summarize: Every time you call the above `if-else` statement, only **one** case will be executed. Returning to above cases is not intended.
If you give a more detailed explanation on what it is that you are trying to do, I could provide further assistance.
Furthermore, I see a lot of duplicated code in your cases (for example the last two seem to be identical, making the first obsolete). You should try to minimize this.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the ordering of your clauses, and the fact that the first condition that evaluates to `true` is the only block that will execute. You may want to change your logic slightly if you expect some of the previous conditions to apply regardless of whether or not `AgentsAvailable == 0`

```
// *** Agents available logic ***
if (e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable > 0)
{
    // Stuff that needs to happen if Agents are available
}
else
{
    // Stuff that needs to happen if they're not available
}

// *** Queue ring logic *** (happens regardless of agents available
if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > 5)
{
}
else if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > 0)
{
}
else
{
}
```

If you have stuff that needs to happen only when there are agents available AND `InQueueInRing` is `> 5`, then you would need to add that inside one of the `if` clauses, for example:

```
if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > 5)
{
    if (e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable > 0)
    {
        // Do stuff here that requires agents available
    }
    else
    {
        // If there's some counterpart logic for when 
        // no agents are available, do it here
    }

    // Do other stuff here that doesn't care about agents one way or the
    // other (i.e. stuff that should ALWAYS happen when InQueueInRing > 5
}
```